# Upsert with .net sqladapter

Tags: .net, sql, optimization, upsert

```
   Dim sSelect As String = _
        "SELECT * FROM Contacts" & _
        " WHERE DataSetID = @DataSetID AND ID >= @FirstID AND ID <= @LastID ORDER BY ID"


        Dim dsDBFiles As New DataSet()
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSelect, m_connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nFirstID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nLastID

        Dim daTable As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim bldr As New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(daTable)

        daTable.Fill(dsDBFiles, sTable)
        Dim tbl As DataTable = dsDBFiles.Tables(sTable)

        Dim rdr As New Data.DataTableReader(dsFiles.Tables(0))
        dsDBFiles.Load(rdr, LoadOption.Upsert, tbl)

        daTable.Update(dsDBFiles, sTable)
```

Is there way to achieve this upsert functionality without retrieving the records ? I am using SQL Server 2005. I heard there is a way to use the sqladapter to do this, without running the select statement.

I am trying to speed up this process. Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT part is one thing - inserting new rows is not a problem.

If you want to update existing rows, you'll need to do the following things:

- add all the rows you want to update to your DataSet (this adds them with a RowState = `Added`, so they would be handled by the INSERT statement)
- call the `.SetModified()` on those rows to set their RowState to `modified`. Now, the UPDATE statement will pick those up and apply them to the database

Of course, you'll also need to set the `UpdateCommand` on your SqlDataAdapter, and you'll need to make sure the SQL UPDATE statement works in such a way that it only compares e.g. the primary key to match up rows to be updated.

With this, you **should** be able to add modified rows to your DataSet and update them without ever retrieving them in the first place.

Marc